# VBA- Paste Values error

Tags: vba, excel

I am trying to paste values from another excel worksheet but my code below keeps returning an error. What am i doing wrong ?

Set tempWB = Application.Workbooks.Open(vrtSelectedItem) 'This OPENS the reference workbook

```
Sheets("Portfolio Worksheet 8.8").Select 'SELECT  A SHEET if you need to
Range("B16:B30").Select 'select SOME RANGE
Selection.Copy 'COPY SOME RANGE

mainWB.Activate 'activate your main workbook
Sheets("Sheet1").Select 'select target sheet
Range("C20").Select 'select target cell
ActiveSheet.PasteSpecial xlPasteValues 'paste the data from the reference worksheet

tempWB.Save 'save and close the reference workbook
tempWB.Close
```

Answer (score 1):

No need for any selecting or copy-pasting

```
Set tempWB = Application.Workbooks.Open(vrtSelectedItem) 

With tempWB.Sheets("Portfolio Worksheet 8.8").Range("B16:B30")

    mainWB.Sheets("Sheet1").Range("C20").Resize(.Rows.Count, _
                                                .Columns.Count).Value = .Value
End With

tempWB.Save 'save and close the reference workbook
tempWB.Close
```

Comment: Thanks this worked after changing the Sheet1 Range to Range("B16:B30")

Answer (score 0):

It doesn't look like you have declared your variable 'mainWB' ?

Comment: Oh sorry i didn't put the whole code since it would take space code works with just the paste function, when i do paste values it gives me an error

Comment: Try: Sheets("Sheet1").Range("C20").PasteSpecial xlPasteValues
    Application.CutCopyMode = False

Answer (score 0):

This below worked, thanks for suggestions, however if i want to copy paste several ranges at the same time. So the code below returns a "Next without for" error. I think this second part of the code in ** is causing the problem

Set tempWB = Application.Workbooks.Open(vrtSelectedItem) 'This OPENS the reference workbook

```
                ' Sheets("Portfolio Worksheet 8.8").Select 'SELECT  A SHEET if you need to


               With mainWB.Sheets("Sheet1").Range("B16:B30")

                tempWB.Sheets("Sheet5").Range("B16:B30").Resize(.Rows.Count, _
                                           .Columns.Count).Value = .Value
                **With mainWB.Sheets("Sheet1").Range("D16:D30")
                tempWB.Sheets("Sheet5").Range("D16:D30").Resize(.Rows.Count, _
                                           .Columns.Count).Value = .Value**

                End With

                tempWB.Save 'save and close the reference workbook
                tempWB.Close

       Next vrtSelectedItem

    Else 'The user pressed Cancel.
    End If
End With

Set fd = Nothing 'Set the object variable to Nothing.
```

End Sub